# Proving statement about dilation of linear operator

Tags: proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve the following problem about the dilation of an invertible operator on a real inner product space $V$. For a fixed operator $T$, this is defined as
$$
D_T = \frac{\sup \{|Tv| \colon |v| = 1 \}}{\inf \{|Tv| \colon |v| = 1 \}}.
$$
The problem is:

> Let $\lambda_{s}$ and $\lambda_{l}$ denote the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $T^{*} T$. Prove that $D_T^2$ is equal to $\frac{\lambda_{l}}{\lambda_s}$ and $D_{T_1 T_2} \leq D_{T_1} D_{T_2}$.

I'm very confused on how to get started on this problem or even proving that there exist eigenvalues. If I knew that $T$ were self-adjoint, I'd be able to say something about the eigenvalues. Without it, I don't know how to get started.